# FormTab error in react-admin not working with div

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am new to react. And I am using `react-admin` framework. There is issue which i can't find a solution till now.

I am using `FormTab`  component in `EDIT` and using their `required()` method for validate the `NumberInput` field, Everything goes superb if i use `NumberInput` element without `Div` tag. But when i use `NumberInput` inside a `Div` then everything works fine except `FormTab` error.? Tab is not getting red text if we use NumberInput`inside a`Div.

`enter code here`

```
<Edit {...props}  undoable={false} title={<EditTitle />} >
    <TabbedForm validate={validateInvoice} toolbar={<PackageEditToolbar />} >
        <FormTab label="Name">
            <DisabledInput label="Id" source="id" className="w20" />
            <TextInput source="szName" label="Package name" className="w20" validate={required()}/>
            <SelectInput validate={required()} 
                source="iActive" label="Status" className="w20"
                choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: 'Active' },
                    { id: '2', name: 'In-Active' }
                ]}
            />
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Product Prices">
            <div style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>Product prices</div>
            <ArrayInput source="price_product" label="" style={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'0px'}} className="price_feild">
                <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd >
                    <PriceFeild styleName="productprice"/>
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>   

            <div className="TabFormHeading">Channel fee</div>

            <NumberInput source="iCNBPrice" label="C&B Prices" className="w20-fl" validate={priceFieldValidation}/>
            <NumberInput source="iBEPrice" label="BE Prices" className="w20-fl"  validate={priceFieldValidation}/>
            <NumberInput source="iEmailPrice" label="Email Prices" className="w20" validate={priceFieldValidation}/>

            <div className="row w100">
             <div className="col-sm-9">
                <div className="TabFormHeading">BE convert fee</div>
                <NumberInput source="iMaxConvert" label="Converts greater than" className="w20-fl" validate={NoofcasesValidation}/>
                <NumberInput source="iConvertFee" label="Convert fee" className="w20"  validate={priceFieldValidation}/>
             </div>
             <div className="col-sm-3">
                <div className="TabFormHeading">BE service agreement</div>
                <NumberInput source="iServiceCharge" label="Monthly service fee"  validate={priceFieldValidation}/>
                </div>   
            </div> 
            <div className="TabFormHeading">Insurance channel fee</div>
            <ArrayInput source="insurance_channel_price" label="" style={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'0px',marginBottom:'0px'}} className="price_feild">
                <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd >
                    <PriceFeild />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>



            <div className="TabFormHeading">Extra services</div>
            <ArrayInput source="addtional_service" label="" style={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'0px',marginBottom:'0px'}} className="price_feild">
                <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd >
                    <PriceFeild />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>

        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Invoice Time ">
        <div className="Heading">Time to invoice</div>
            <TextInput source="szError" label=""  style={{ display:'none'}}/>
            <CheckboxGroupInput source="iInvoiceEOM" className="m-tb-none" label="" choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: 'EOM / End of month' },
            ]} />
            <CheckboxGroupInput source="iInvoiceDate" className="m-tb-none" label="" choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: 'Every 10. in each month' },
            ]} />
            <CheckboxGroupInput source="iInvoicePropertySold" className="m-tb-none" label="" choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: 'Property is sold' },
            ]} />
            <CheckboxGroupInput source="iInvoiceRecurring" className="m-tb-none" label="" choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: 'Recurring invoice' },
            ]} />
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Discount Prices ">
        <div style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>Magazine number discount</div>
            <SelectInput className="w20-fl" source="iMagazineDiscountPeriod" label="Discount Period"
                choices={[
                    { id: '1', name: '1 Month' },
                    { id: '2', name: '2 Month' },
                    { id: '3', name: '3 Month' },
                    { id: '4', name: '4 Month' },
                    { id: '5', name: '5 Month' },
                    { id: '6', name: '6 Month' },
                    { id: '7', name: '7 Month' },
                    { id: '8', name: '8 Month' },
                    { id: '9', name: '9 Month' },
                    { id: '10', name: '10 Month' },
                    { id: '11', name: '11 Month' },
                    { id: '12', name: '12 Month' },
                ]}
            />
            <NumberInput source="iDiscountAfterMagazine" label="No of magazine" className="w20" />

            <div className="TabFormHeading">Product type discount</div>
            <ArrayInput source="product_type_discount" label="" style={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'0px',marginBottom:'0px'}} className="price_feild productTypeDiscount ">
                <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove disableAdd className="productTypeDiscount">
                    <PriceFeild />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>

        </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>

</Edit>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @ravibagul91  I have edited the question and entered the code.

Comment: @ravibagul91 do u have suggestions on this